# How to navigate back after button Segue in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have two views, both are UIViewControllers, the first one contains a tableview with a button that segues to a camera view which is the second one.

So The first ViewController has been done in storyboard, including the segue to the second ViewController which is done by a "Show". The second ViewController has been done mostly in code, I have a UIImageView which I have added a selector method too which I want to use to navigate back to the first ViewController when pressed.

How do I do this in code as currently the UIImageView overlay I have created for the second ViewController which presents the camera view entirely in code.

Currently this is what I have created in code to initiate the method

```
//.....
UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Avatar_Mel"];
    UIImageView *avatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myImage];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mySequeMethod)];
    avatar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [avatar addGestureRecognizer:tap];
//.....

- (void)mySequeMethod {
//   what should I do here? How to I show the first view controller again?
}
```

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
If you just want to pop one level back up the navigation stack.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If second controller is modally presented

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In case of navigation stack

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```